# PyBrain: When creating network from ground up how and where do you create a bias?

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

Following the [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) documentation, [Building Networks with Modules and Connections](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html), I'm building a neural network piecewise (in contrast to using the buildNetwork shortcut).  I'm constructing a simple 3-layer (input, hidden, output) neural network.  How do I properly add a bias unit?

I'm guessing I construct a `BiasUnit` module as in:

```
b = BiasUnit(name='bias')
network.addModule(b)
```

Is this the right way? Do I have to create `FullConnection` object? If so, what should I be connecting?

Comment: As much as I love python, I've switched to using the C-based [fanntool](http://code.google.com/p/fanntool/) which blows PyBrain out of the water in terms of performance.

Answer (score 10):

Realized PyBrain is open source and I have the source code sitting in my Python directory.  I opened the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\shortcuts.py file.  Inside this file I located the buildNetwork function and saw how it adds BiasUnit's.  The relevant code is here:

```
...
n = Network()
# linear input layer
n.addInputModule(LinearLayer(layers[0], name='in'))
# output layer of type 'outclass'
n.addOutputModule(opt['outclass'](layers[-1], name='out'))
if opt['bias']:
    # add bias module and connection to out module, if desired
    n.addModule(BiasUnit(name='bias'))
    if opt['outputbias']:
        n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['bias'], n['out']))
# arbitrary number of hidden layers of type 'hiddenclass'
for i, num in enumerate(layers[1:-1]):
    layername = 'hidden%i' % i
    n.addModule(opt['hiddenclass'](num, name=layername))
    if opt['bias']:
        # also connect all the layers with the bias
        n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['bias'], n[layername]))
# connections between hidden layers
...
```

Basically it looks like it creates a single BiasUnit and connects it to each hidden layer and optionally to the output layer as well.

Comment: Good detective work. Note the buildNetwork is just a shortcut and in the API documentation they discuss building a network (look at the docs for Network)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [simple example](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/977acf5f362ffa3c71a944210fd6d9f7695df053/examples/supervised/backprop/backpropanbncn.py):

```
n = RecurrentNetwork()
n.addModule(TanhLayer(hsize, name = 'h'))
n.addModule(BiasUnit(name = 'bias'))
n.addOutputModule(LinearLayer(1, name = 'out'))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['bias'], n['h']))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['h'], n['out']))
n.sortModules()
```

Note that the `BiasUnit` is connected to `TanhLayer` effectively making the `h` layer a layer with bias.